# Issues with character inflating in android webView in chienese language

Tags: android, webview

currently i am setting my html response in webview, now, chienese character in that response is not setting up in my web view, but character is setting up properly in my computer browsers like Mozilla and chrome. i have Problem with this "`&amp;#32957`" My response is as following:

*蘊含蝦紅素、半胱胺酸胜&#32957;、維他命Ｃ等美容成分
*有助整頓肌膚的代謝循環
*抑制黑色素的形成
 *打造充滿透明感的美白肌
*清新荔枝口味

Now Mywebview's xml is as following:

```
               <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wvProductItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now i am setting that data in my java class as under:

```
        String detail=responseFromWeb;        

        wvProductDetail.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvProductDetail.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wvProductDetail.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wvProductDetail.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        wvProductDetail.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        wvProductDetail.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        wvProductDetail.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        wvProductDetail.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Scroll Bottom:" + scrollView.getBottom());
                    scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
                        }
                    }, 500);

                }
            });
        wvProductDetail.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
                    detail, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Right Problem**

that is the problem with escape sequence if we write `"&amp;"` then it will convert to `"&"` but if you write like this `"&amp;#32957"`then web view first convert escape sequence `"&amp;"` to `"&"` and after its going to convert `"#32957"` unicode so result will be this ====== >`"&#32957;"`.

so above problem is happening with you.

**Solution** for your specific problem.

you have to replace `"&amp;#"` with `"&#"`

eg.

```
 wvProductDetail.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
                    detail.replaceAll("&amp;#", "&#") "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```